# i get indexoutofbound exception from matcher dot find

Tags: java, regex

im facing a bug, where my Code only works if two of my RegEx (my RegEx is looking for Text1) are not written next to each other. For example i have a `text ="Text1, Text2, Text3"` -> Everything works fine.
If i had something like this `="Text1, Text1, Text2, Text3"` -> My Code throws an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

I think it has somethin to do with `matcher.find()` but i couldnt figure out how it exactly works.

```
int i = 0;
while(matcher.find()) {
    if(!array.contains(matcher.group())){
        try {
                    array.add(i, matcher.group());
                    array.set(i, array.get(i).replaceAll("\\.",""));
                    array.set(i, array.get(i).replaceAll("\\W","-"));

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    i++;
}
result="";
```

Comment: Could you provide a bit more context about the array variable and your regex?

Comment: Did you try using a debugger to find your bug?

Answer (score 1):

You increment your counter (`i`) even if you don't add anything to your array. Next time you try to access the current item, your index is to large, resulting in an `IndexOutOfBoundException`.